# How to add CSS on Struts 2 form page

Tags: java, css, jsp, struts2, struts-validation

In my Struts 2 application I am trying to add CSS style, but it is not displaying on the page. When I click on the submit button two times and after showing validation error *only* then CSS is displaying. Please tell me what is the resume of this kind of problem my form is here

```jsp
<%@ page language ="java" contentType ="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding ="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-dojo-tags" prefix="sx" %> 
 <html>
    <head>
       <sx:head/>
    <script type="text/javascript"  src ="script.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/emp.css">
        
    </head>  
    
<body>
          
        <div id ="did" align="center"> <h1 style="color: red">  ENPLOYEE REGISTRATION FORM</h1>
       
   <s:form  action="emplogin"  method="post" >
      
      <s:textfield name="firstname" label="Employee Firstname"/>
      <s:textfield name ="lastname" label ="Last name"/>  
      <s:textfield name ="id"  label="Id"/>
      <s:radio name ="gender"   list="{'male', 'female'}" label = "Gender"/>
    <sx:datetimepicker name="dob" displayFormat="dd-MMM-yyyy"  label="DOB"></sx:datetimepicker> 
      <s:radio  name ="maritalstatus" list="{'singale','married'}" label="Marital Status" />
       
      <s:textfield name ="email" label ="Email" />
 <sx:datetimepicker name ="joiningdate" displayFormat="dd-MMM-yyyy" label="Joining Date" ></sx:datetimepicker>
      
      <s:textfield name= "designation" label = "Designation"/>
      <s:textarea name ="address" label ="Address" />
      <s:textfield name = "country" label ="Country" />     
      <s:textfield name  ="state" label = "State" />
      <s:textfield name  ="city" label ="City"/> 
      <s:textfield name ="pincode" label ="Pincode"/>
      <s:textfield name ="mobileno" label="Mobile No"/>
      <s:select   name ="groups" list="{'group 1', 'group 2', 'group 3'}"  label ="Group"  />
     <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
        <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <s:submit align="center"></s:submit>
      </s:form>
       </div>
    </body>
 </html>
```

**CSS file is:**

```css
#did
{background-color:#6495ed;}

#trasition
{
transition: width 2s;
-webkit-transition: width 2s; 
}
```

Comment: I don't see any "class" in your html. Are you styling based on tags directly? Can we see your CSS?

Answer (score 1):

You have mistake with the syntax of the style attribute

you should replace this

```
cssStyle="{width:184px"
```

to

```
cssStyle="width:184px;"
```

also dojo tag library is deprecated in struts2 since version 2.1. Use [struts2-jquery](https://github.com/struts-community-plugins/struts2-jquery) instead.

Comment: I am not asking about that my problem is when i am using css from an external file which i described in <head> section it is only working when i am clicking submit button e times  not directly. I am just trying to change color of baground.

Comment: @tom struts2 applying theme on the elements. use the theme you want for the custom formatting or simple theme to define a custom theme for your barebone html elements.

Comment: can you just tell me why normal way css is not working in my page and when clicking on submit button 2 times(after validation message)it only working

Comment: @tom the document has errors and not point to the browser what it is and how it could be render html, version etc. If youare using `devMode` better to turn it off to produce seamless result to the viewer.

Comment: Even after turning of devmode it is not working .Is there any connection b/w css and struts2 validation?

Comment: Has nothing rather than using theme to render validation errors.